# Segmentation Error when using a shared library

Tags: linux, g++, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Im building a shared library on linux. the library ".so" was sucessfully created, but when I tried to link it to a test application (with an empty main) and run the executable I got a segmentation error : "Segmentation error (cure dumped)"

when I tried to debug it with gdb and check the backtrace I got this output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0073d5df in std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12.1-4.i686 libgcc-4.4.5-2.fc13.i686 libstdc++-4.4.5-2.fc13.i686 zlib-1.2.3-23.fc12.i686

(gdb) backtrace

#0  0x0073d5df in std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x0012d70c in ?? () from /opt/cuda/lib/libcudart.so.3
#2  0x0012df0c in ?? () from /opt/cuda/lib/libcudart.so.3
#3  0x0012c88a in ?? () from /opt/cuda/lib/libcudart.so.3
#4  0x00121435 in __cudaRegisterFatBinary () from /opt/cuda/lib/libcudart.so.3
#5  0x005d7bfd in __sti____cudaRegisterAll_55_tmpxft_00000fe6_00000000_26_MonteCarloPaeo_SM10_cpp1_ii_3a8af011()
    () from libsharedCUFP.so
#6  0x005db40d in __do_global_ctors_aux () from libsharedCUFP.so
#7  0x005a8748 in _init () from libsharedCUFP.so
#8  0x008abd00 in _dl_init_internal () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
#9  0x0089d88f in _dl_start_user () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Im not familiar with gdb debugging, and it's the first time Im trying to build a shared library on Linux, but it seems to me that it has something to do with the library dynamic linking.

If anyone had any idea about this error and could help me, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have anything to do with dynamic linking or shared libraries - one of the constructors in libsharedCUFP.so (I assume this is your shared library) is most probably passing an illegal address to a function in libcudart.so which crashes.

You simply need to debug your code.

Comment: actually in my shared lib Im linking CUDA objects (compiled with NVCC) and for some reason some fucntion calls were not working. The only solution i could find was to separate the cuda files and build them into a static lib in addition to the .so. Anyways thanks for your help.